# What is wrong with this JQuery AJAX code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I was facing some problem with AJAX code. I was using MVC3 for our project. My requirement is bind the dropdown value using AJAX when page load. What happens when loading the page, the AJAX request send to the controller properly and return back to the AJAX function and binds the exact values in dropdown. But sometimes (When page refreshed or first time load) its not binding retrieved value. Rather its showing default value. Pls see my code and suggest me where i am doing wrong.

**Edit:** Even i tried to use async property to false. Its not at all send to the controller action method for getting the data.

**Code**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUser", "Invoices")',
            data: "{'id':" + JSON.stringify(currval) + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#User-" + curr).select2("data", { id: data.Value, Name: data.Text });
                $(this).val(data.Value);
            }
        });
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am sure, but isn't the `this` context is bound to the `xhr` object in success function?

Comment: Are you waiting for the document.ready event to fire before sending the ajax request? If you're not, it's entirely possible you're hitting a race condition where the ajax request completes before the DOM is ready and there's no element for the data to be bound to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your Action method is below

```
public JsonResult hello(int id)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and JQuery should be like below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currval = 2;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'URl',
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: currval }),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your `data` property incorrectly. Try this:

```
data: { id: currval },
```

Comment: @Kenneth He'd be passing it all as a JSON string using his code, not as an actual value (matching `public ActionResult GetUser(int id)`).

Comment: Which may be what he wants ... As he said: "Sometimes it's not binding retrieved value." That means he's retrieving the value correctly so there must be something wrong on the receiving end, what he's sending should be alright

Comment: @Kenneth Maybe because it's throwing errors at the receiving end, but they're being masked